# how to divide information after extracting data from multiple tags using BS4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am new in Python. I have problem when extracting list from documents. My sources file is not really html but it has a tag to extract data needed.

[image]

I manage to extract the data i  needed using this code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = r"E:\Python\Sources\test.review"
page = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
for review in soup.find_all(['review_text','product_name']):
    tokens=review.get_text()
    print tokens
```

However the problems how to break the result as i not really familiar working with list in Python. I try using this code, but its only return first data. I believe it because it refer to first data in file. Thanks for all your feedback.

```
rvwTxt=soup.review_text.string
pName=soup.product_name.string
print rvwTxt
print pName
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the XML as code.

Answer (score -1):

You can group in a dict, using the tag name to do the grouping so you can do it in a single pass:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(),"xml")
d = {"review_text":[], "product_name": []}
for review in soup.find_all(['review_text','product_name']):
    d[review.name].append(review.get_text())
```

Or using two list comps:

```
rev = [r.text for r in soup.find_all('product_name')]
prod = [p.text for p in soup.find_all('review_text')]
```